Number of 3D Volumes bounded by the intersection of a sphere and the $\binom{n}{3}$ planes that are formed by any $n$ points
Assuming $n$ points are, at random, placed on the surface of a sphere, and every possible plane corresponding to 3 of these points is created, how many different bounded regions are formed? There are some restrictions on how these points may be placed. For example, no 4 points may be coplanar (this causes for overlapping planes), no nine points may form some arrangement of three planes which all share a line (this "reduces" some potential regions to a volume of 0).
I was inspired by the question of determining how many areas are formed by placing $n$ points on a circle and connecting all the possible lines. The function for the number of areas formed for $n$ points on the circle is $f(n) = 1 + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4}$, so I would assume that if a generic formula existed for the problem in a higher dimension, it would take a similar form.
I have calculated values so far, with $3$ points corresponding to $2$ volumes, $4$ points: $11$ volumes, $5$ points: $54$ volumes, and $6$ points: roughly 280 volumes. I have seen some conjectures for such a function on OEIS: https://oeis.org/A144841 with a formula of $f(n) = 280\cdot \binom{n}{9} + 10\cdot \binom{n}{6} + 6\cdot \binom{n}{4} + \binom{n}{3} + 1$. I have no idea how these coeffecients were calculated and I doubt this is correct, as I have written code, graphed the volumes and planes on desmos, and drawn greatcircles on a giant balloon for the case $n=5$, and everything results in 54.
One of the approaches to solve the 2D version ($n$ points on a circle) is by using the Euler Characteristic. Can this principle still be applied when dealing with the sphere and planes? I believe that $V-E+F-R=0$ where $R$ denotes the number of distinct 3D regions. Is this equation correct? It seems right and I have verified it for many cases of points and greatcircles including cases for $n=3$ and $n=4$.
